# Checking iCloud for existing content

Tags: core-data, icloud

What is the best way to check iCloud for existing data?

I need to check that data doesn't exist on the local device, or iCloud so I can then download it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the `core-data` tag I'm assuming you mean that you're using Core Data rather than iCloud file APIs or the ubiquitous key-value store.

With Core Data's built-in iCloud support, you check on existing data in exactly the same way as if you were not using iCloud. Once you create your Core Data stack, you check what data exists by doing normal Core Data fetches. There's no (exposed) concept of local vs. cloud data, there's just one data store that happens to know how to communicate with iCloud. You don't explicitly initiate downloads-- they happen automatically.

- At app launch time when you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`, Core Data internally initiates the download of any data that's not available locally yet. As a result this method may block for a while. If it returns successfully, then all current downloads can be assumed to be complete.
- If new changes appear while your app is running, Core Data will download and import them and, when it's finished, will post `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` to tell you what just happened.

This all describes how Core Data's iCloud is *supposed* to work. In practice you'll probably find that it doesn't always work as intended.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, it seems that on the device i build the app for first as a clean build (i.e. removing icloud data and local data) that this first device is the only one who leaves a receipt in icloud as well as saves the data there. The second device just hangs on trying to add the persistent store to icloud

Comment: First: Doing a clean build has absolutely no effect on iCloud data. If you want to remove that, go to System Preferences to delete it, and to http://developer.icloud.com/ to make sure it worked. Second: Blocking for a long time trying to add the persistent store is normal (or if not "normal", at least typical). Wait a while and see what happens.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I meant removing from icloud as in the developer.icloud.com site. After some time i get an error `Safe save failed for file, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file upload timed out." UserInfo=0x1dd65320 {NSLocalizedDescription=The file upload timed out.}` and only one of my two stores (with local data - not affected by iCloud) is added to the persistent stores

Comment: File a bug, this kind of meaningless error message is typical of Core Data's iCloud integration. It doesn't mean you're doing something wrong, so it's not something you can fix.

Comment: OK, not the answer I wanted hear but not our fault! Thanks anyway for you help

Comment: If you're not already targeting iOS 6, raising the bar *might* help. Although there are still some significant issues, a lot was fixed in the update.

Comment: Yeah, I'm specifically targeting iOS 6.1 for iCloud and other security/various updates

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tom Harrington for pointing out, this error is nothing to do with the developer/coding - it's purely to do with iCloud/Apple/connection issues.

More on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098022/icloud-time-out-using-icloud-core-data-magical-record) I found.